# How to catch exception in asp.net view rendering?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, view

I see there is a nice [HandeError] attribute which could be applied on controller class or method.
What is my options if I would like to catch and handle exceptions which ocurred during rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i prefer to use the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    // do something with the exception
}
```

**Edit re comment**

ASP MVC is still ASP.NET, so yes this still works fine.

If some some reason you want to handle Rendering errors differently, you could override the default `WebFormsViewEngine` and wrap a `try catch` around the view generation methods, thats a bit overkill though.

Comment: Yes, this is nice method which worked fine in asp.net. I was sure it is not supported by mvc... 
I will check and accept answer then